# What will happen when an event gets fired from a task?it will have separate thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, event-handling, task

What will happen when an event gets fired from a task?it will have separate thread or the same task path?

Comment: a task needs to do a notification to parent object. does that notification create separate thread or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are asking about, but the event handler will be executed on the task's thread, as demonstrated by this simple test:

```
class Test
{
    delegate void update();
    static event update updateEvent;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        updateEvent += new update(Test_updateEvent);
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                updateEvent();
            });
        t.Wait();
    }

    static void Test_updateEvent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Parent thread: 1
Task thread: 3
Event thread: 3
```

Comment: +1, yes - firing events is a 'normal' stack-based call/return mechanism and cannot change thread state, (unless the delegate function performs inter-thread signaling within itself).